# Should i use repository pattern for updating a single field? If so, how?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, repository-pattern, generic-method

i have like about 10 controller that have the exact same method, the only thing that changes is the table, and it is to update a single field from a table(explained better ahead)... So i was thinking about creating a method on my interface of generic repository for that...

The thing is, the class where i implement those methods doesn´t know what table we talking about, so i can´t reach the column, and of course, the columns have a diferent name...

More specific, i want to update order of a record.. if i place the record from 1 to 3 it changes those records order from 1 to 3.. This happens exacly in all the tables, each table as a field called OrderCompany or OrderCountry, etc... Since i cant get the field, how am i suposed to update in the repository ?

my code to update :

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task UpdateOrderAsync([FromBody] OrdemModel ordemObj)
        {
            using (var db = _context)
            {
                int ordemFinal = 0;

                //guardar item a ser movido
                var itemPegado = await _context.RH_Cargos.FindAsync(ordemObj.itemAMover);
                if (ordemObj.itemOndeFoi != 0)
                {
                    var itemFinal = await _context.RH_Cargos.FindAsync(ordemObj.itemOndeFoi);
                    ordemFinal = (int)itemFinal.OrdemCargos;
                }

                
                //update a todos os valores intermedios quando é para aumentar a ordem do item
                if (itemPegado.OrdemCargos < ordemFinal)
                {
                    var areas = db.RH_Cargos.Where(x => x.OrdemCargos > itemPegado.OrdemCargos & x.OrdemCargos <= ordemFinal).ToList();
                    areas.ForEach(o => o.OrdemCargos -= 1);
                }

                //update a todos os valores intermedio quando é para diminuir a ordem do item
                if (itemPegado.OrdemCargos > ordemFinal)
                {
                    ordemFinal++;
                    var areas = db.RH_Cargos.Where(x => x.OrdemCargos < itemPegado.OrdemCargos & x.OrdemCargos >= ordemFinal).ToList();
                    areas.ForEach(o => o.OrdemCargos += 1);

                }

                //guardar o item que se quis mover para o spot certo
                itemPegado.OrdemCargos = ordemFinal;

                //guardar
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Any help is appreciated! thanks :)

Comment: Using a "generic" repository on top of an ORM like Entity Framework is an **anti**pattern. Right now you already have a Unit-of-Work, named `_context`. A DbContext *is* a Unit-of-Work. You have a repository (with a strange name) called `RH_Cargos`. A DbSet *is* a Repository. If you *don't* call `SaveChanges` at the end, all changes are discarded, which is how a Unit-of-Work works. Check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories or Unit of Work with EF Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/)

Comment: Even if you wrote a repository without EF, you'd need to clean up this code. It doesn't try to update a single field, it decides which query to execute based on some parameters. *Most* of those queries can be replaced with a single on. For example, you could write `if(someOption) { query=query.Where(...);}` to add a `Where` clause conditionally. Or you could use `if` or even a switch expression to pick which `Func<T,bool>` to use with your `Where`

Comment: The first block could be replaced with `RH_Cargos.Where(c=>someids.Contains(c.ID)).Select(c=>new {c.ID,c.OrdemCargos})`. That would generate `WHERE ID in (@id1,@id2...)` and would load only the relevant fields instead of the entire row

Comment: I have been reading a lot and i have read before that i didn´t need to.. but also i get people saying that i should use... That is driving me crazy since there is like a lot of people in both sides and i am new to this...

Comment: You are using Id's and i dont use Id's anywhere, so i got confused when you said i should replace my first block with that...

Comment: One more thing, even if i dont create repository, and i want to make that code generic, how do i do it? i dont want to have that code in all of my controllers, i just should call that method... shouldnt i?  :/

Comment: Yes, a lot of people blindly copy "best practices" without thought. Which is good for tthe consultants brought to fix the problems afterward. What *actual problem* do you expect to solve? The definition of `pattern` is `A solution to a problem in a context` - the same problem may require a *different* solution in a different context. For example, StackOverflow uses `Dapper`, a micro-ORM instead of repositories and ORMs.

Comment: EF Core is already generic. Your code's *logic* though needs improving. Instead of loading objects one by one, paying the network delays multiple times, read them all at once. Make the modifications you want, then persist them. Or *don't* use an ORM at all - you don't have to. If you can write an `UPDATE .. SET OrdemCargos=OrdemCargos +1 FROM ... WHERE ...` that does what you want, do it. It will be 1000 times faster - there will be only one query that executes atomically. No data will be sent to the client

Comment: I am going to be honest, but i am way to confused right now... So EF Core already has Unity of Work and repositories, that means it´s useless to use Repository pattern right ?
What you mean by EF Core is already generic? i have methods repeated over and over by controllers that were basic Copy/Paste because the only thing that change is the tables, just like that one... That is not generic? 

Also, then how do i update the table records, if i dont go one by one? i need to go one by one and update the ones that have that expression to true, no ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a PocoGenerator (for example https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator) to create repository classes, each of which can inherit a base-class repository with common properties/methods but this sounds like a good example of somewhere where you should not be over-abstracting it. If you have different tables and are updating different columns then you are doing different things and should have clear explicit code that shows this rather than hiding behind a forced abstraction.

Otherwise you could use a number of patterns like [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) but if the problem is just your code above, I would leave it as it is, it doesn't look too bad.

Comment: The thing is that is repeated to much, i have like 8 controllers for this method, and the only thing that changes is the table and the Order field name... 
So shouldn´t i create a generic method?  
lets say i want to change a thing in the method, right now i have to change it in 10 diferent places... that feels bad :/

Comment: What if you use an Interface in your model classes? Newer Versions of C# support default implementations for Interfaces.

Comment: @Klamsi what do you mean  by that? Can you give me a simple example ? (no need to be the code above)

Comment: public class RH_Cargos: DbSet<...>, ICanDoOrdering. And in the Interface you require the name of the order column and add a default implementation for MoveToPos(element, toIndex). I hope I got your problem right

Comment: I think you understood my problem, but i did not understand what i got to do .. So i create an interface wich has my method right? And in that interface i can get the entity and the column ? 
and then what? i simply use that method on my controller? this is kinda weird.. can you give me an example where u use a generic method to update a given table and a given field?